# Is it safe to delete a linked list in its own destructor?

Tags: c++, exception, linked-list, destructor

I want to clean up any resources I acquired earlier, so in my destructor I call the function `clear` that deletes the whole linked list:

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList() {
    clear();
}
```

Is it safe to do that? Is there a chance of an exception? This is what `clear` looks like:

```
// deletes all nodes in a linked list
void LinkedList::clear() {

    Node* current = head;

    while (current) {

        Node* next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;

    }

    head = nullptr;

}
```

Comment: Yes, IMO that's fine, you **should** be doing this if you don't want to require your user to `clear()` manually before destruction (and you definitely don't want that).

Comment: Looks fine to me. As long as you don't do something like `delete this;` in the destructor :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you usually do in LL destructors. Your LinkedList class is just a wrapper around the chain of Nodes, so it is safe as long as you check for null pointers in other LinkedList methods.

Also if this is not your computer science home task, consider using std::list :)